# Detecting long press in list of CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, core-graphics

I have a list of objects that have a visible `CAShapeLayer` on my view.

```
internal class Line {
    var layer = CAShapeLayer()
}
```

These are displayed on an object of type `UIView`. On the `UIView` I have a longPress gesture recognizer which should detect a long press on one of the line.layers.

This is what I got

```
@objc private func didLongPress(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    var selectedLine: Line?
    let touchPoint = sender.location(in: self)
    if sender.state == .began {
        for line in lines {
            if line.layer.contains(touchPoint) == true {
                print("true")
            } else {
                print("false")
            }

        }
    } else if sender.state == .changed {
        for line in lines {
            if line.layer.contains(touchPoint) == true {
                print("true")
            } else {
                print("false")
            }

        }

    } else if sender.state == .ended {
        for line in lines {
            if line.layer.contains(touchPoint) == true {
                print("true")
            } else {
                print("false")
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Needless to say, it only prints false. Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution in:

```
line.layer.path?.boundingBox.contains(touchPoint)
```